# Using path aliases how to identify node IDs from database and based on these IDs how to publish them?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type called article. For this content type, I unchecked the "*Published*" checkbox under the publishing options tab.

I have 30000 nodes I changed to unpublished. Among those, I want to publish 900 records. I have the node URLs.

Using the path aliases, how to get the node IDs? Once I have the node IDs, how can I publish those nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`drupal_get_normal_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_normal_path/7.x) to get the `node/id`-paths for each of them.

Then you can use the following code to publish them.

```
// Load the node object.
$node = node_load($nid);
// Set the status property to 1.
$node->status = 1;
// Re-save the node.
node_save($node);
```

Comment: How to save status change only? If we give node_save($node) then all the changes get saved. I want status change only get saved.

Comment: not sure I get the question, you only change the status value here, so that the one that's changed in the new saved object right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the path alias, you can easily get the normal path and then the node object with two single functions. I assume you have the path alias available in the `$path_alias` variable.

```
$path = drupal_get_normal_path($path_alias);
$node = menu_get_object('node', 1, $path);
```

Once you have the node object, you just set `$node->status` to [`NODE_PUBLISHED`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/constant/NODE_PUBLISHED/7.x), and save the node. So the full code becomes the following.

```
$path = drupal_get_normal_path($path_alias);
if ($node = menu_get_object('node', 1, $path)) {
  $node->status = NODE_PUBLISHED;
  node_save($node);
}
```

I am not sure how much safe it's assuming the path aliases are for nodes, but just to be sure, and avoid trying to load a node when Drupal didn't find any normal path matching the path alias, I would use the following code.

```
$path = drupal_get_normal_path($path_alias);
if (strpos($path, 'node/') === 0 && ($node = menu_get_object('node', 1, $path))) {
  $node->status = NODE_PUBLISHED;
  node_save($node);
}
```

Notice that `===` is necessary, since `strpos()` can either return `0` to mean the path starts with `'node/'`, or FALSE to mean `'node/'` was not found in the path. (In PHP `0 == FALSE` is `TRUE`.)